# How to start a Salesforce Developer Group?

Tags: discussion

I was trying to find a Salesforce Developer Group near me using the [MeetUp](https://www.meetup.com/fr-FR/pro/salesforcedevs/) platform. There were some groups in my country, but unfortunately, far away from where I live.

So I was thinking: "Maybe you should try to ask Salesforce to become a group leader in your town."

First, I emailed the address specified on the MeetUp platform.

But after two weeks with no answer, I started searching somewhere else. So I found an another email address on this [article](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Start_a_Salesforce_Developer_User_Group). Same result after two weeks.

Finally, I filled the form that I found on this [website](https://sites.google.com/site/salesforcedevelopergroups/start-a-group) two weeks ago.
No answer yet.

So I can understand that the answer is no. But I would like at least to have an answer.

Is there supposed to have another way to contact Salesforce about this?

Comment: I tried to email both you and the contact I have, but it looks like their address bounced. :(

Comment: Thanks @AdrianLarson. You rock. Too bad their address bounced... Salesforce MVP and not Salesforce Developer Group Leader yet? This should be quick !

Comment: I'll post to the chatter group and see what folks say.

Comment: @pchittum - do you have a contact Martin should reach out to in EMEA dev evangelists?

Comment: That group has probably been very busy with TDX17. They've also recently been reorganized in terms of alignment and who they report to. They now fall under the Trailhead umbrella as does the Success Community. I'll reach out today to find out who best to contact as it recently changed a few months ago. We'll get you an email address.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I contacted Holly Firestone who at one point was responsible for Salesforce User Groups and Salesforce Developer User Groups. Organizationally, things are in transition at Salesforce, so what I'm about to relay will likely change over the coming months. She told me to have you contact support@salesforceusergroups.com. They've been CC'd on my correspondence with her and will be looking for your email.

I want to take a moment and add that I'm pleased to learn that you're going to start a DUG where you live. It's a lot of work, but I'm confident you'll find it very rewarding. I know the devs in your community will be happy that you made the effort. My involvement in the Dallas Developer Group has been a very enjoyable experience.

Comment: Hi @crmprogdev. Thank you very much for your help. I don't know yet if they will accept but if they do, could it be possible to ask you some advices? I guess this is a lot a work but I believe the efforts will be rewarded. I realized, since the first day I came here (i.e. 1 year and 9 months ago), that mutual aid and communication are the best way to learn. And that's why I'm so motivated about this.

Comment: I just sent the email. ****crossing the fingers****

Comment: Would be happy to provide whatever assistance I can Martin. You can contact me on the Success Community or via Twitter. We can connect further from there.

Comment: Just to keep you up-to-date, the Bordeaux Salesforce Developer Group is launched ! Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Congrats! That's awesome and great news to hear Martin! :-)